# How to specify same column name in different field while fetching data in mysql wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

i am trying to fetch value from two tables of mysql database with same column name.now i am in trouble to specify column,means in two tables i have same column named contact_name.I have to contact name from both tables.i can't understand how can i identify that contact name come from which table..please help.

My query is

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tbl_ratings,tbl_providers,tbl_members where tbl_ratings.provider_id=tbl_providers.provider_id and tbl_ratings.member_id=tbl_members.member_id" );
```

In both tbl_providers and tbl_members i have to fetch contact name saperatly.thanx in advance.

Comment: May it will help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496703/mysql-multiple-tables-access-query][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496703/mysql-multiple-tables-access-query

Comment: select *,table.contact_name as contactfirsttbl

Answer (score 1):

use alias

with an example as i don't have your column name

For example if you have two table with one column id having same name

use

```
   $sql = "Select first_table.id as id1 , second_table.id as id2 from first_table,second_table";


the above query when  executed will return first_table id with name id1 & second_table id with name id2
```

Answer (score 1):

Oherwise use code like this...

```
 $result ="SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->post2cat ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->post2cat.post_id) WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'paragraf' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->post2cat.category_id IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC";
```